# How to find min of each column attribute in pyspark sql rows type data in python given as dictionary to a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, pickle

I've the data extracted from a pickle file and it has column which have data of type dictionary. The data is of the following format:
Orders

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1006 | {'0': Rows(amount=100, quantity=10), '1': Rows(amount=95, quantity = 2)} |
| 1007 | {'0': Rows(amount=100, quantity=10), '1': Rows(amount=95, quantity = 2), '2': Rows(amount=1000, quantity = 3) } |
| 1008 | {'0': Rows(amount=100, quantity=10) |

The required output is to get the minimum of amount and quantity corresponding to each id:

| ID | Data | Amount | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1006 | {'0': Rows(amount=100, quantity=10), '1': Rows(amount=95, quantity = 20)} | 95 | 10 |
| 1007 | {'0': Rows(amount=322, quantity=17), '1': Rows(amount=196, quantity = 12), '2': Rows(amount=1000, quantity = 3) } | 196 | 3 |
| 1008 | {'0': Rows(amount=100, quantity=10) | 100 | 10 |

The noted point is the type of value of key value pair present in Data column is pyspark.sql.types.Row and the key values can be variable for each row of dataframe Orders.

Comment: This **the type of Data column is `pyspark.sql.types.Row`** doesn't sound right to me. Can you run `df.printSchema()` and post the result?

Comment: @pltc the type of Data column is object not the one I mentioned before but the type of the value derived from the key value pair of Data column is of type pyspark.sql.types.Row